# Do I have to purchase java license to use Jenkins?

Tags: java, oracle, licensing, jenkins

We are using Jenkins to build and deploy apps to production and staging. While migrating our Jenkins Servers to a newer server, we have realized that apparently Java RTE now requires a license to use. Is this actually the case or am I missing something? What alternatives can I use as Runtime Environment, only to run Jenkins?

Comment: You can rephrase (edit) question to: Are there non-Oracle Java RTE I can run Jenkins under, now that Oracle has changed their licensing terms? Answer is yes: [OpenJDK](http://openjdk.java.net/install/), [AdoptOpenJDK](https://adoptopenjdk.net/releases.html), [OpenJ9](https://www.eclipse.org/openj9/), [Azul Aulu](https://www.azul.com/downloads/zulu-community/?&architecture=x86-64-bit&package=jdk) and [others](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Java_virtual_machines), each with [different benefits](https://dzone.com/articles/java-and-the-jdks-which-one-to-use).

Comment: Jenkins make specific recommendations for [Java Requirements](https://jenkins.io/doc/administration/requirements/java/) and specific notes regarding [upgrading to Java 11](https://jenkins.io/doc/administration/requirements/upgrade-java-guidelines/) and [running on Java 11](https://jenkins.io/doc/administration/requirements/jenkins-on-java-11/), though they may be out-of-date. Must be running Jenkins 2.164.1+